# Bash Script for healthcheck linux

Tags: json, bash, linux, shell

I have below bash script which i have written to check the health of different storage component and then creates an incident through service-now tool.

This is script is working fine for me but i think this can be improved as i written this while learning through different google sources.

I would appreciate any help on improvisation of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M")
clusters=(udcl101 udcl2011 udcl3011 udcl4011)
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:$PATH

incident=$1
sysid=UNKNOWN

checkvaultenv=$(echo $vaultenv | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
if [[  "$checkvaultenv" == "" ]]
then
  vaultenv=prod
else
  if [[  "$checkvaultenv" != "dev" &&  "$checkvaultenv" != "test" && "$checkvaultenv" != "acc" && "$checkvaultenv" != "prod" ]]
  then
    echo unknown vault environment specified: $vaultenv
    exit 1
  fi
fi
vaultenvlc=$(echo $vaultenv | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
vaultenvuc=$(echo $vaultenv | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')


SNOW_USERNAME=$(export EDITOR=cat ; ansible-vault view --vault-password-file=~/.ssh/sss.str.${vaultenvlc} ~/iss/vaults/vault-${vaultenvuc}.yml | awk '/vault_servicenow_username/{gsub(/"/, ""); print $2}')
SNOW_PASSWORD=$(export EDITOR=cat ; ansible-vault view --vault-password-file=~/.ssh/sss.str.${vaultenvlc} ~/iss/vaults/vault-${vaultenvuc}.yml | awk '/vault_servicenow_password/{gsub(/"/, ""); print $2}')


case $vaultenvlc in
  ram)
    SNOW_INSTANCE=udc2dev.service-now.com
    ;;
  iqa)
    SNOW_INSTANCE=udc2dev.service-now.com
    ;;
  dev)
    SNOW_INSTANCE=udc2dev.service-now.com
    ;;
  test)
    SNOW_INSTANCE=udc2trn.service-now.com
    ;;
  acc)
    SNOW_INSTANCE=udc2qa.service-now.com
    ;;
  *)
    SNOW_INSTANCE=udc2.service-now.com
    ;;
esac

SNOW_AUTH=$(echo -n $SNOW_USERNAME:$SNOW_PASSWORD)

create_incident()
{
  url="https://${SNOW_INSTANCE}/api/now/table/incident"
  curloutput=$(curl -sslv1 -u $SNOW_AUTH -X POST -s -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" $url -d "$variables" 2>/dev/null)
  RETURNCODE=$?
  if [ "$RETURNCODE" == "0" ]
  then
    incident_number=$(echo $curloutput |  python -c $'import sys, json\nprint json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]["number"]')
    sysid=$(echo $curloutput |  python -c $'import sys, json\nprint json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]["sys_id"]')
    echo "OK: created incident $incident_number with sysid $sysid"
  else
    echo "ERROR creating incident:"
    echo "======================================="
    echo $curloutput
    echo "======================================="
  fi
}


# sets the variables for the incident
set_variables()
{
read -r -d '' variables <<- EOM
{
  "short_description": "$snshort_description",
  "assignment_group":  "RD-DI-Infra-Storage",
  "contact_type":      "interface",
  "state":             "New",
  "urgency":           "3 - Low",
  "impact":            "3 - Low",
  "cmdb_ci":           "$udcl",
  "u_sec_env":         "Normal Secure",
  "description":       $body
}
EOM
}


# checks if file is empty *or* has only "", if not create incident
chk_body()
{
  if [[ $body == "" || $body == '""' ]]
   then
    echo empty body
   else
    set_variables
    echo $variables
    echo ""
    create_incident
  fi
}

# actual storage health checks

for udcl in "${clusters[@]}";
do

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl aggr show -root false | awk '/^udc/ && $4 >= 92 {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="aggr utilization above limit"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl "ro 0;snapshot show -create-time <21d" |awk '/^stv/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="snapshots older then 21 days"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl "ro 1;event log show -time <8h"| awk '/netinet.ethr.duplct.ipAdr|secd.ldap.noServers|object.store.unavailable/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="eventlog netinet.ethr.duplct.ipAdr, secd.ldap.noServers, object.store.unavailable messages"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl "ro 1;event log show -severity EMERGENCY -time <8h"| awk '/udc/ && !/netinet.ethr.duplct.ipAdr|secd.ldap.noServers|object.store.unavailable/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="EMERGENCY messages"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl "ro 0;system healt alert show"| awk '/Node|Severity|Proba/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="system healt alert show messages"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl "ro 0;vol show -volume *esx* -percent-used >=85" | awk '/stv/ && !/dr/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="ESX volumes utilization more then 85"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@$udcl "ro 0;vol show -state offline -fields aggregate" | awk '/stv/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="Validate offline volumes"
  chk_body

done
```

Comment: You can double quote all the variables except consonants as you are using bash and can use  array and then call into the for loop that's more elegant thank using `$(echo $clusters)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

- Quote variables unless you have a good reason not to quote them.
  How about a password `* $(touch /tmp/sorry) *` ?
- Use `${parameter:-word}` for turning an empty `vaultenv` into `prod`.
  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
- Translate uppercase to lowercase only once. Use `${parameter,,}` for this.
- Combine tests on `vaultenv` into one block.
  Your code will exit for `ram` and `iqa`, I accept these. Change when you want to exit.
- Changed variable names to lowercase
  UPPERCASE is reserved for system vars like `PATH`.
- Removed unused `DATE`.
- I combined the two `ansible-vault` calls into one and assign to `SHOW_AUTH` without `echo`.
- Removed assignment to RETURNCODE

The resulting script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clusters=(udcl101 udcl2011 udcl3011 udcl4011)
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:$PATH

incident="$1" # Unused ???????
sysid=UNKNOWN

vaultenv="${vaultenv:-prod}"
vaultenvlc="${vaultenv,,}"
vaultenvuc="${vaultenv^^}"

case "${vaultenvlc}" in
  ram)
    # or do you want to exit here?
    snow_instance=udc2dev.service-now.com
    ;;
  iqa)
    # or do you want to exit here?
    snow_instance=udc2dev.service-now.com
    ;;
  dev)
    snow_instance=udc2dev.service-now.com
    ;;
  test)
    snow_instance=udc2trn.service-now.com
    ;;
  acc)
    snow_instance=udc2qa.service-now.com
    ;;
  prod)
    snow_instance=udc2.service-now.com
    ;;
  *)
    echo "unknown vault environment specified: ${vaultenv}"
    exit 1
esac

snow_auth=$(export EDITOR=cat;
             ansible-vault view --vault-password-file=~/.ssh/"sss.str.${vaultenvlc}" ~/iss/vaults/"vault-${vaultenvuc}.yml" |
             awk '
               /vault_servicenow_username/ {gsub(/"/, ""); usr=$2}
               /vault_servicenow_password/ {gsub(/"/, ""); pw=$2}
               END {printf("%s:%s", usr, pw)}
             ')

create_incident()
{
  url="https://${snow_instance}/api/now/table/incident"
  if curloutput=$(curl -sslv1 -u "${snow_auth}" -X POST -s -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" "${url}" -d "${variables}" 2>/dev/null); then
    incident_number=$(echo "${curloutput}" |  python -c $'import sys, json\nprint json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]["number"]')
    sysid=$(echo "${curloutput}" |  python -c $'import sys, json\nprint json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]["sys_id"]')
    echo "OK: created incident ${incident_number} with sysid ${sysid}"
  else
    echo "ERROR creating incident:"
    echo "======================================="
    echo "${curloutput}"
    echo "======================================="
  fi
}


# sets the variables for the incident
set_variables()
{
read -r -d '' variables <<- EOM
{
  "short_description": "${snshort_description}",
  "assignment_group":  "RD-DI-Infra-Storage",
  "contact_type":      "interface",
  "state":             "New",
  "urgency":           "3 - Low",
  "impact":            "3 - Low",
  "cmdb_ci":           "${udcl}",
  "u_sec_env":         "Normal Secure",
  "description":       ${body}
}
EOM
}


# checks if file is empty *or* has only "", if not create incident
chk_body()
{
  if [[ "${body}" == "" || "${body}" == '""' ]]; then
    echo empty body
   else
    set_variables
    echo "${variables}"
    echo ""
    create_incident
  fi
}

# actual storage health checks

for udcl in "${clusters[@]}";
do

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" aggr show -root false |
     awk '/^udc/ && $4 >= 92 {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="aggr utilization above limit"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" "ro 0;snapshot show -create-time <21d" |
     awk '/^stv/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="snapshots older then 21 days"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" "ro 1;event log show -time <8h"|
     awk '/netinet.ethr.duplct.ipAdr|secd.ldap.noServers|object.store.unavailable/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0} 
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="eventlog netinet.ethr.duplct.ipAdr, secd.ldap.noServers, object.store.unavailable messages"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" "ro 1;event log show -severity EMERGENCY -time <8h"|
     awk '/udc/ && !/netinet.ethr.duplct.ipAdr|secd.ldap.noServers|object.store.unavailable/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="EMERGENCY messages"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" "ro 0;system healt alert show"|
     awk '/Node|Severity|Proba/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="system healt alert show messages"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" "ro 0;vol show -volume *esx* -percent-used >=85" |
     awk '/stv/ && !/dr/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="ESX volumes utilization more then 85"
  chk_body

  body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" "ro 0;vol show -state offline -fields aggregate" |
     awk '/stv/ {sub(/\r$/, ""); s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
          END {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}')
  snshort_description="Validate offline volumes"
  chk_body

done
```

I am not sure about introducing a new function for all your ssh calls:

```
for udcl in "${clusters[@]}";
do

  body=$(check "${udcl}" aggr)
  chk_body

  body=$(check "${udcl}" snapshot)
  chk_body

  body=$(check "${udcl}" showtime)
  chk_body

  ...
}

check() {
   case "$2" in
   "aggr") 
      body=$(ssh admin@"${udcl}" aggr show -root false |
         awk '
           /^udc/ && $4 >= 92 {sub(/\r$/, "");
           s = (s == "" ? "" : s "\\n") $0}
           END    {printf "\"%s\"\n", s}
         ')
     snshort_description="aggr utilization above limit"
     ;;
    ...
   esac
}
```

Comment: Thank you Walter  for the detailed answer, +1 for the same and i am testing the same, will accept this after testing.